# Are the Light Domain Cleric cantrips in addition to the 3 starting cantrips?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cleric

The *Cantrips known* chart for a level 1 cleric states you know 3 cantrips at level 1. The light domain cleric at level one gets the light cantrip if she doesn't already know it.

So, does a light domain cleric get 4 cantrips at level 1? Could I take 3 other cantrips and then be granted Light from my domain?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, and this and Nature are the only Domains that gets an extra cantrip, so other clerics still have 3 at first level while Light and Nature Domains gets 3 *plus* **Light** / **(Druid cantrip)**.

All the clerics get bonus cantrips as they grow up levels as you can see in the Player's Handbook (PHB) **page 57**, starting at 3 and reaching 5 at level 10th, the Light and Nature clerics will have his extra **Light** / **(Druid cantrip)** cantrips, so they are an exception between clerics.

Comment: @GMNoob Yeah, corrected it. Is not listed "Bonus Cantrip" as the one in Light Domain, so missed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You are exactly right. All 1st level Clerics get 3 Cantrips known at 1st level, and some of the domains do give you additional Cantrips, as well as other benefits and extending your list of prepared spells.

The Light Domain gives you the Light Cantrip if you don't already have it, so that you now have 4 Cantrips. Some Races and other features also give Cantrips and limited spell-casting capabilities, like the Tiefling giving you the Thaumaturgy Cantrip if you don't already know it.

Comment: So does that mean they get *4 cantrips* at level 1? Whether this answer's currently answering in the affirmative or not is unclear given you state 3.

Comment: Also, while you're obviously right, your answer could use some backing up.